# Could not initialize PECL extension even though memcached installed

Tags: drush

I am migrating a site from one remote server to another. I have set up the new server will all the prerequisites installed memcached server and its extension too. But when I try to run drush cr I get the error `Could not initialize  PECL extension`

I wrote a simple php code to check if memcached is running and if the php code is able to read and write to memcached and it works just fine. Please find sample code below

```
<?php

$memcache = new Memcached;
$memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";

var_dump($get_result);

?>
```

My issue is I keep getting the error as shown below

```
In DrupalMemcachedFactory.php line 53:

  Could not initialize  PECL extension
```

Would anyone of you have any idea why this might be happening? How do I get this sorted?

Comment: There aren't many details here to help with, but most likely the php configuration that your command-line php is using is different from the php configuration that your web server is using.

Comment: @mradcliffe you were right, somehow the command-line php was running a different version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and after some digging I found that the issue was due to multiple php versions installed on server.

By default Drush uses the system php to run and in our case it didn't have any extensions loaded since it wasn't serving any websites.

Try to run drush using absolute path to the website's php like so:

```
/usr/bin/php74 /path/to/drush cr
```

*This assumes that the php74 executable is in /usr/bin which is usually the case*